# I have to make public URLs for private actions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Lets say I have a website where I allow users to perform actions (communicate, post photos, etc) on their friends on my site (they are friends on Facebook). This is private information between User A and User B.

Before the new Open Graph [beta] I would encode as much information as needed in the original `POST` request. But now Facebook has moved to a more "callback" scheme where I do a simple `POST` and provide a URL which FB then hits via `GET` and I provide series of `og:` tags to describe the core content - all of this is the information that I would have PREVIOUSLY provided in the first and only `POST` request.

Here in lies the problem though: I have to provide a completely un-authenticated URL for FB to hit (the `GET`) and it has to be the same URL the app will use in the Timeline, so I cannot make a special, secure by obscurity URL as the callback, but provide a "friendly" URL (which would require authentication) to be used as the click through URL in the timeline.

Am I understanding this correctly?

EDIT: this would also be a different issue if FB when doing the callback `GET` would provide some kind of authentication data in the URL or HTTP headers, but after examining the complete HTTP details in the `GET` request FB is giving us nothing other than a special `User-Agent` that we can use to differentiate the request.

UPDATE: I believe this question is driving at the same issue. IF we can provide a different `og:url` on our gibberish "callback" page then it would make things a lot easier.

[Can You Have Your OpenGraph Object Link to a Different URL?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7561071/can-you-have-your-opengraph-object-link-to-a-different-url)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure open graph is the best solution for your application?

By definition the actions go into a user's timeline so if you simply want to share a generic action "i.e. Ted answered Cody's question" but not link to that answer as it is private, why not build a static page with the generic information in og: tags and place your link back to that. This way you can share the activity without exposing the details.

In our application many postings occur in in-accessible pages so we've altered public pages to dynamically expose the right og: data when Facebook goes looking. It's not perfect as users can see it but this way we can show nothing for a private entry and everything on a public one.

Comment: Well, I think OG is the right approach. I mean, the approach is still to leverage Facebooks inherent security controls and privacy, so our action is not truly private between User A and User B - it should be visible my mutual friends, etc. Or whichever privacy level we decide to use. That being said, this new OG approach implies I make a TRULY public URL to describe this interaction between User A and User B. Of course to make these URLs not guessable means I have to make them secure by obscurity and use random seeming URLs (?)

Comment: We do want our action information to be visible across the graph as defined by User A and User B - mutual friends, friends of friends, etc.

Comment: My point is this: we're NOT trying to do anything different than the previous Graph API - its just that the new OG model implies we make "public" URLs (e.g. ones not behind any kind of authentication) for "private" information that was previously specified in the run-time `POST /wall` or whatever. Facebook has required us to increase exposure. I just find that odd